# ASP repeater not filling all items

Tags: asp.net, asprepeater

I have a repeater that works wonders.Now I need to verify if a record exists in a DB and if it does, do not show the dropdowns but other textboxes. If there is only 1 record, it works, but if it sees more than 1, it does not. Here is the code:

Main ASPX:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repStudents" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="reasonStd" runat="server">
                                      <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Select Reason" Value="-1"></asp:ListItem>
                                         OPTIONS...
                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="reasonLabel" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                            <span>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="dateForStudents" type="date" runat="server" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="dateLabel" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </span>
```

This is the backend:

```
List<ASF.FinanceCenter.Entity.Student> dt = dbStudents.GetAllByFamilyId(int.Parse(lFamilyId.Text)); <--- This fills the same number as repeater
            int i = 0;
            DropDownList students;
            TextBox txtStudents, lastDay, reason;
            foreach (ASF.FinanceCenter.Entity.Student studentinos in dt)
            {
                students = repStudents.Items[i].FindControl("reasonStd") as DropDownList;
                txtStudents = repStudents.Items[i].FindControl("dateForStudents") as TextBox;               
                lastDay = repStudents.Items[i].FindControl("dateLabel") as TextBox;                            
                reason = repStudents.Items[i].FindControl("reasonLabel") as TextBox;              
                reason.Visible = true;
                students.Visible = false;
                txtStudents.Visible = false;
                lastDay.Visible = true;
                lastDay.Text = GetDataLastDay(studentinos.Id.ToString());
                reason.Text = GetDataReason(studentinos.Id.ToString());
            }
                i++;
```

What I am getting is kinda weird, because it does not fill all the options, say there are 2 items in the repeater, it just works on the first, but the second it looks like it does nothing, although if I debug, the values to fill in the boxes are correct, it gets them correctly from the DB. The last one in the backend, its inside a method I call in the Page_Load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, for some reason, the i++ was outside the foreach. Dumb mistake due to fatigue.